# Compiler error "setter method needed" to use dot syntax -- setter is defined

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, properties, compiler-errors, getter-setter

I can't figure out why my getter and setter code is not working. In some example code I was going over:

```
- (NSArray *)sushiTypes {
  return _sushiRolls;
}

- (void)setSushiTypes:(NSArray *)sushiRolls {
  [sushiRolls retain];
  [_sushiRolls release];
  _sushiRolls = sushiRolls;
}
```

Then in:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];
  self.sushiTypes = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"...]autorelease];
}
```

The whole time, this worked, but a property for `sushiTypes` was never declared. I (sort of) get how this works, since it works the same as a setter/getter regardless of whether it was synthesized or not.

But here's my code, and I get a compiler error asking for a property. Did I miss something?

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Temp0 : NSObject {
    NSNumber *x1;
}

-(NSNumber *)x1;
-(void)setx1:(NSNumber *)x;

@end
```

---

```
//
#import "Temp0.h"

@implementation Temp0

-(NSNumber *)x1 {
    return x1;
}

-(void)setx1:(NSNumber *)x {
    [x retain];
    [x1 release];
    x1 = x;
}

-(id)init 
{
    self.x1 = [[NSNumber alloc]initWithInt:1];    // Error on this line:
    // Setter method is needed to assign to object using property assignment syntax
    [super init];
}

@end
```

[Screenshot of this code and the error in Xcode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VttcZ.jpg)

Comment: Youve got the answer below but note that your init method is not right - you have to do self = [super init] first, and also return self at the end of the method -  unless you'd omitted that code for clarity.

Comment: Oh, I didn't add the code. I forgot it, but thanks for reminding me!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's standard to capitalize the first letter of the property in the setter method name. As you correctly have in:

```
-(void)setSushiTypes:(NSArray *)sushiRolls
```

So `setX1:` is the expected method signature.

```
-(void)setX1:(NSNumber *)x1;
```

Comment: So it was all just a typo? :|

Comment: Yup. If you declare properties as properties, autocomplete will autocomplete your method signatures for you. You don't necessarily have to use `@synthesize`.